# images from static folder in nuxt 3 doesn't show

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm using Nuxt 3

and this is directories structure

[image]

images are loaded like this

```
<img src="/images/index/pic-left.svg" />
```

I've also tried (start without `/` )

```
<img src="images/index/pic-left.svg"  />
```

and it didn't worked again

What's the problem ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[In Nuxt3](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/public#public-directory), the directory is now `public` and not `static`.

So it should be `/images/index/pic-left.svg`.